# Cómo Hacer que se autocomplete mis demás Texbox de mi formulario rellenando un dato(TextBox)ID en ASP WebForms?

Tags: c#, webforms

*Estoy Intentando hacer en mi formulario que al momento de ingresar un dato único de mi DB en mi Texbox, ésta que realice un autocompletado de mis demas Texbox y los almacene en sus respectivos TexBoxes.
es en ASP Web Forms con Visual Studio y Sql Server. C#
Es decir al momento de ingresar El Libro,Foja y Partida (INT), que busque en la base de datos y si lo encuentra esos datos guardados que los autorrellene los demas datos en los demas TexBoxes a cada cual corresponda !
Alguien que me pudiera ayudar, Gracias...!*

```html
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label class="">Libro, Foja y Partida</label>

                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtLib" class="form-control" placeholder="Libro ..."></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtFoj" class="form-control" placeholder="Foja ..."></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtPart" class="form-control" placeholder="Partida.."></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Nombre</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtNom" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre ..."></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Apellidos</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtApePat" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Paterno..."></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtApeMat" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Materno..."></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Nombre de Padre</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtPadre" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del Padre"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Que libreria tienes pensado usar para implementar el autocomplete? Usaste jquery con WebMethod? o pensavas usar los componente de ajax toolkit?

Comment: aporta algo mas de detalle porque sino van a cerrar la pregunta porque es muy generico lo que planteas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que noto es que falta algo que genere la accion al servidor como ser un `<asp:Button>` asp.net de busqueda.

Si ingresas libros, forja y partida tambien estos podrian ser combo con las opciones para seleccionar. Al usar `DropDownList` podrias asignar el `AutoPostBack = true` y tener el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` en el servidor para realizar la busqueda y completar los demas controles.

[Populate TextBox based on DropDownList Selection in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-TextBox-based-on-DropDownList-Selection-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

en el articulo solo usa un solo combobox, pero la idea es similar ya que debes usar el `WHERE` del `SELECT` para obtener el resto de los datos

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();

string strQuery = @"select City, Country from Customers where
                      CustomerID = @CustomerID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", ddlCustomers.SelectedItem.Value);     

    
SqlDataReader sdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sdr.Read())
{
    txtCity.Text = sdr["City"].ToString();
    lblCountry.Text = sdr["Country"].ToString(); 
}
```

esa es mas o menos la estructura para obtener los datos y completar el resto de los textbox

Comment: Hola Gracias Hermano, pero para un textbox no consigo solucionarlo. no tendrás una idea al respecto o algun ejemplo. "el DropDownList si ayuda pero en este caso ocupo tres datos de entrada para poder devolver una respuesta" .   Gracias

Comment: Un textbox tambien debe definir la propiedad AutoPostBack = true para asi tener disponible el evento TextChanged que se lanzara cuando detecte un cambio al sacar el foco